# Making Feature specs less erratic/brittle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, specifications

I am writing features specs to ensure that my app's `Add Task` behavior is functioning properly. I've ran the same spec multiple times without editing the code at all, and occasionally one or both of the specs fail.

I'm wondering if there is something specific I am doing that makes my specs behave erratically (is this what devs mean when they talk about brittle specs? I'd imagine so...). I added comments to clarify the code. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

**task_feature_spec_helper**

```
include ApplicationHelper

def click_task
  visit order_path(order.id)
  click_link("Add Task")
end

def add_valid_task
  click_task

  within("#add_task") do
    select 'foo1@example.com', from: 'Assignee'
    fill_in 'Due at', {:with => '15/03/25'}
    fill_in_html("task__textarea", {:with => task[:description]})
    click_button "Save"
    end
end

def add_empty_task
  click_task

  within("div#add_task") { click_button "Save" }
end
```

**task_feature_spec**
    require 'spec_helper'

```
feature 'Create Task' do
  let(:order) {create(:order)}
  let(:task) {attributes_for(:task)} #using attributes for to prevent extra object 
  before(:each) {login_user}          #initliaztion (user squence only goes up if the user is 
                                       #saved.)

  scenario 'with valid description' , :js => :true do

    add_valid_task
    expect(page).to have_content('Task Created')   #'Task Created' is a momentary JS notification
    sleep 1                                         #this pause allows elements below to render

    within("div#tasks-table") do
      expect(page).to have_content('Due on 03/15/25')
      expect(page).to have_content('Assigned to foo1@example.com')
      expect(page).to have_content('Displayed on Ad Hoc')
    end
  end


  scenario 'with invalid (empty) description' , :js => :true do

    add_empty_task
    sleep 1

    expect(page).to have_content("can't be blank")
  end 
end
```

Comment: your ajax request should change your dom. If so, don't use `sleep` (ever), use `should have_selector` to ensure the ajax has been made.

Comment: I should use `should have_selector` to ensure that `Task Created` appears? Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the spec `expect(page).to have_content('Task Created')`. Since this was a JS toastr message, I was having a tough time isolating it, and in the end I decided that testing for it wasn't so important to the app's overall functionality. I also had to remove `Due on` because this would pass half the time and fail the other half, even though it would a) be entered on the bot browser and b) appear on the bot page after being entered. Since I was able to enter it, I decided that testing for its presence wasn't essential.

While debugging, I came across this article which was helpful by [Jonas Nicklas](http://www.elabs.se/blog/51-simple-tricks-to-clean-up-your-capybara-tests) in terms of cleaning up my specs.

Finally, I ended up leaving `sleep` in my specs, and in fact increased it to `sleep(10)` and this increased the likelihood of the specs passing.

Comment: I am coming across this answer two years later and just like to point out that I wholeheartedly disagree with you. Feature specs should be testing something from soup to nuts; simply not testing something because it is difficult does not justify ignoring it. Also, having sleep in your specs is a huge no no for dependency issues as well as bogging down your suite. Not to mention if you use a CI it's a nightmare.